# Changing TimeZone in Jasmin Unit Test using momentJS

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, momentjs

I have a problem with TimeZones when testing my Angular app. For instance in my Angular component I have the following method that takes some arguments and returns a translated string or a date that is formatted using the Angular Pipe

```
public testStatus(isTestDue: boolean, lastTestDate: any): string {
    if (isTestDue || lastTestDate < 1000 || !lastTestDate) {
      return this.i18Next.transform('ns.common:test.required');
    } else if (lastTestDate > 1000) {
      return this.datePipe.transform(lastBumpDate, 'medium');
    }
}
```

Now I write a test for the method like so

```
describe('testStatus', () => {
  fit('should return "Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:12 AM"', () => {
    expect(component.testStatus(false, 12345)).toBe('Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:12 AM');
  });
});
```

Now this works when I run my tests locally (my time zone is Central European Standard Time). However when my app is built on the Bamboo server I get an error:

> Expected 'Jan 1, 1970, 12:00:12 AM' to be 'Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:12 AM'

It seems that the Bamboo Server is using "Coordinated Universal Time" (it is, I checked by writing a `new Date()` to the console). So I thought I would try to change the timezone in my test so it would work locally and on the external build server. I changed my code thus so I use momentJS and `jasmin.clock()` to set the timezone ...

```
describe('testStatus', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    jasmine.clock().install();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });

  fit('should return "Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:12 AM"', () => {
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(moment.tz('Europe/Berlin').format());
    expect(component.testStatus(false, 12345)).toBe('Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:12 AM');
  });
});
```

When experimenting with timezones and trying to get the test to fail locally (by setting to `moment.tz('Europe/London')` I have realised that the timezone isn't being changed locally or remotely. Can someone help me determine how I can set the date to use Coordinated Universal Time or a specific timezone? Or and I approaching this test incorrectly? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi mike, how did you manage to solve this ?